# Do I have to handle my bags when transiting in Istanbul?

Tags: transit, luggage, ist

I booked a flight from Fiji to the UK via Auckland - Hong Kong - Istanbul - Gatwick. Do I have to claim my baggage in Hong Kong? We will change airlines there from Air NZ to Turkish Air.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You will change airline at Hong Kong since Air New Zealand doesn't fly to Istanbul, so I'd expect any baggage issues to arise there, yet your title is asking about Istanbul.

Answer (score 8):

If it's a single booking/ticket: depends

If these are two separate bookings/tickets: yes

Comment: Can you provide any source, clarification etc?

Comment: @guest While that's probably possible, it's standard practice and quite simple. You need to return your luggage at the end of your flight. If your flight has a stop-over, that's not the end. If you have connected 2 flights yourself, that's 2 flights, 2 times collecting luggage. If the booking agent has connected 2 flights, I'd ask them.

Comment: @Mast If it's a stopover, you sometimes have to collect your bags and re-check them.  For example, any stopover where the previous leg is an international flight into USA. You must get your bags on your first landing in USA and re-check them, even if you're then flying out of the USA again.

Comment: @Mast: i had the same experience as Aleks G in Moscow.

Comment: I have too much reputation for my edits to be queued for a peer review. I apologize with @Hilmar for changing their answer without warning. This time I would have preferred a peer review

Comment: This one is pretty cut and dry: Air New Zealand and Turkish Air are Star Alliance code share partners and it's an international to international connection. If it's a single ticket, the bags WILL be checked through unless there is something extremely usually about the itinerary. @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ: what do you think it depends on ?

Comment: E.g. mandatory customs in Hong Kong. I never visited HK, but you know that no matter how far you are traveling, if you enter the US you must collect your bag and clear customs. Same is true for China, so I wouldn't **bet** HK to be tooooooo different.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ There is no such thing as "mandatory customs in Hong Kong".

Comment: The OP asks specifically about Istanbul.

Comment: Uhmmm... sir... maybe someone edited the question... but I see "Do I have to claim my baggage in Hong Kong?"

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was going by the title.

Answer (score 5):

You must check your bag tag at the time of initial bag drop for a final answer. The bag tag displays the airport code you will be retrieving your bag.

As @Hilmar answered, if your booking is on different PNRs (Passenger Name Record), ie. separate tickets, the answer **is a final yes**: you will have to hand your bag for every leg that is covered by a new ticket. Plus, you will pass security check again, as you need to leave for check-in area.

You did not disclose how you bought tickets.

In the case your ticket is a *real* single ticket bought from a single airline, **that depends**. If airlines have agreements, and if you don't cross mandatory-customs checkpoints, it's likely that they will check your bag **through**. This may particularly be the case of subsidiaries (e.g. Turkish Airlines / Anadolu jet, my personal experience).

If you purchased a single ticket by a ticket dealer (travel agency, online dealer like Kiwi.com, see example later) that may not necessarily be the case. Your reseller may be selling you a single ticket that is *backed* by multiple reservations, thus you fall in the **no** case. See Kiwi example later. Kiwi is just one of the many online resellers around.

In fact, when I buy extremely cheap flights from certain portals, despite being single tickets, check-through is often not a possibility.

**Personal experience**: for example, long ago I bought a single RIX->VIE->MXP->ATH <strike>campaign</strike> journey for a few euros on Kiwi.com via Skyscanner. I did a single payment and had a single reservation, but while I had explicit guarantee of flight reprotection from Kiwi, I had *clear* indication both that any checked bag should be retrieved at Vienna and Milan (but I was traveling hand luggage only), and I also had different maximum sizes for hand bag, forcing me to bring a bag of the smallest size allowed (Lauda/Ryanair). This because Kiwi and other online dealers resell cheap tickets combining them into a single reservation.

I just ran another search on Kiwi for the same trip 19th September, random date for convenience of this post. This time, the trip is via [Sandefjord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandefjord_Airport,_Torp), [Orio Al Serio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orio_al_Serio_International_Airport). As you can see, on a single ticket they require, and tell in advance, that you have to collect your bag at both airports and *self-transfer*. Actually, in the case of same airport, *self-transfer* is a bit odd. A real self-transfer happens when you have to move to another airport, e.g. Heathrow to Gatwitck or Linate to Orio Al Serio, where all transfer is up to you.

The below is explained because Kiwi buys multiple tickets on your behalf

[image: Trip simulator]

In the end, if your travel choice **does not depend** on the ability to check the bag through, I would never ask on a travel forum without specific information on the airlines involved, the exact trip plan and the information whether the PNR is single or multiple.

Comment: I have found that Air New Zealand and Turkish airlines are both member of Star Alliance. You have more chances to have your bag checked through.

Comment: Kiwi is a special case. They pretend to sell a single booking when they are actually completely separate tickets/bookings/PNRs. You’ll have different ticket numbers, different references/record locators. No guarantee whatsoever from the airlines in case of missing connections. No through check-in. Those should really only be booked by seasoned travellers who know what they are doing.

Comment: Correct, no guarantee from airlines.. but from Kiwi themselves (until they do a Thomas Cook-ish exit-from-the-scene)

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience of flying Turkish Airlines many times over the past 10 years, always with a stop-over in Istanbul, I never had to get my bags.  I would drop them in London - and get them in Tbilisi, or Beijing, or Cairo, etc.  Same thing going back.

In fact, once when I missed a connection and had to spend the night in Istanbul (hotel paid for by the airline), I couldn't get my bag even after asking for it.

Note that in my case it has always been a single ticket. If you have different tickets, then you will need to get your bags and re-check them for the second flight.

An exception is when you land in one airport and depart from the other - then it depends on the airline and you should confirm with the airline.